# Can I show funds immediately after selling my stocks for a Japan tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am an Indian national. I sold a good chunk of stocks yesterday and should have the money credited in my account in the next 3 days. I have about 5 weeks to apply for both a Japan tourist visa and a UK student visa. Without this stock money, I do not have enough money as usually expected for Japan/UK visas, but my balance is not too shoddy either.

Processing for a Japan visa takes about 5 days and for a UK visa about 3 weeks. Given that visa officers are generally wary of sudden bumps in cash and I am in a time crunch, I would like to know if the stock sale can pass for a non-suspicious source of funding if I apply for a Japan visa next week. I'm also open to suggestions on anything else I can do.

Comment: Are not the stocks funds at the end of the day? why converting them in cash?

Comment: For UK Visa, I read that only liquid cash proof is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Include proof of the provenance of the funds with your application e.g. stock certifícate (if paper-based) or stock holding statement(s) in your name, purchase and sale confirmation etc and provide a brief explanation regarding the transaction in your application.

Comment: Agreed. It’ll be best if your statement shows when you purchased the stocks. If you bought them just a few months ago, you’ll want to prove the provenance of those funds as well.